# Check if 3/9 texts of dynamically created JButtons matches? (for Tic Tac Toe game)

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jbutton, dynamically-generated

```
JButton button[] = new JButton[9];

for(int i = 0;i < button.length; i++){
        button[i] = new JButton();
        button[i].setText(Integer.toString(i+1));
        frame.add(button[i]);
        button[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
```

What I have is 9 JButtons with name "button". To determine a win, how can I check if 3 button(either in rows, columns, or diagonal) matches. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I give each dynamically created button a different name so it is easier to access?

You don't. They are in an array, a variable that already has a "name", `button`, and so you can access each individual JButton object just fine from the array by using the array indices: `button[2]` for example. Note that myself, I'd rename the array, `buttons`, just so I knew at a glance that it represents multiple JButtons and not just one.

If this is Tic-Tac-Toe, please see [my answers to related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A522444+tictactoe).

---

Additional suggestions:

- I'd use a 2-dimensional array of JButton: `private JButton[][] buttonGrid = new JButton[ROWS][COLS];` where ROWS and COLS are int constants that both == 3.
- I'd create my JButtons in a nested for loop to fill up the grid with JButtons.
- When I need to know which button was pushed, I could iterate through the 2-D array using a nested for loop.

e.g.,

```
private static final int ROWS = 3;
private static final int COLS = ROWS;

private JButton[][] buttonGrid = new JButton[ROWS][COLS];
```

Then to create the buttons in the grid, use nested for loops:

```
  ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
  for (int row = 0; row < buttonGrid.length; row++) {
     for (int col = 0; col < buttonGrid[row].length; col++) {
        buttonGrid[row][col] = new JButton(BLANK);
        buttonGrid[row][col].addActionListener(buttonListener);
        // add to GridLayout using JPanel
     }
  }
```

Note that the ActionListener's actionPerformed ActionEvent parameter can tell you which button was pushed by calling `getSource()` on the object:

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      // get the pushed button:
      JButton selectedButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
```

Then the ButtonListener could iterate through the array to see which button was pushed, again using nested for loops:

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     JButton selectedButton = (JButton) e.getSource();

     int selectedRow = -1;  // initialize with non-viable value
     int selectedCol = -1;

     for (int row = 0; row < buttonGrid.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < buttonGrid[row].length; col++) {
           if (selectedButton == buttonGrid[row][col]) {
              selectedRow = row;
              selectedCol = col;
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of comparing 3 button texts to see if they match?

Comment: @LooseMoose: please clarify your question for me. Which 3 buttons do you mean? How will you decide which to choose? In what context? If this is tic-tac-toe, why not say so from the beginning???

Comment: @LooseMoose: If this is Tic-Tac-Toe, please see [my answers to related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A522444+tictactoe).

Comment: I am using these buttons for tic tac toe game, so to determine who wins I need to check if 3 button(either in rows, columns, or diagonal) matches. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @LooseMoose: please [edit your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29998150/edit) and mention all of this. It is very relevant to your question and so should not be left out. Else your question is very incomplete and others won't be able to help. While you do that, I'll show you some tricks in a minute.

Comment: I understand 2D array and filling with buttons but can you elaborate on 3rd bullet? Btw thanks a bunch

Comment: @LooseMoose: see edits, and also see my links as far as using logic to decide if 3 in a row or column or diagonal match.

Comment: is there any way i can chat with you. I don't know how to